# preserving a contenteditable div selection while having the caret in an text input

Tags: html, selection, range, mouse-cursor, multipleselection

I have a contenteditable div but I want to allow the user to make a selection then click over into a text input field and enter a value without the highlighting of the contenteditable selection to be lost.

Is this possible?  I can hack it in Firefox it looks like.

I get the selection on mousedown and restore the selection on mouseup while the cursor is in the other input but in Chrome when I restore the selection it causes focus to be lost in the input field.  This does not have to work in IE, only in FF, Safari and Chrome.

If it isn't possible with the route I am going, are there any other workarounds to this issue?

Comment: It essentially sounds like you're trying to have focus on two elements at once.  The browser won't allow this because it breaks many of the selection models and callback events.  What is your end goal so we can try to figure out what you're trying to do?

Comment: The end goal is a simple system for changing font size inline.  But its a bit different in that a user should be able to type in the font size they want (12px, 18pt, 4em) opposed to just selecting it from a drop down as that would result in a ton of options.

Unfortunately something like TinyMCE or CKEditor is something I expressly do not want.

Comment: I've done stuff like this in other projects, and what we did was to highlight the selected text by surrounding it in a span and giving it a special class. Then when the user types in the size they want we just search for the span and adjust it that way.  There are several similar ways to accomplish the same, but I highly doubt you'll be able to keep focus on two different pieces.